# Windows XP firewall blocking in-bound UDP packets: programmatic exception for Java program or workaround?

Tags: java, udp, windows-firewall

I have a Java program that is communicating with other programs on a network using UDP packets.  I noticed that on my Windows XP machine, I could not receive in-bound packets, and after some research, I figured out that it was the firewall causing the trouble.

Is there a way to add a firewall exception for a Java program?  Googling doesn't reveal anything for this.

Is there a DOS shell command I can run at install time that will add the exception?  (Also can't find anything on Google for that.)

Is there a way to work around it in a way that lets Windows know the in-bound packets are solicited?  For instance, I'm sending out a broadcast packet, and then other systems respond.  Anything I can do with regard to which ports I use for the broadcast that will allow the response packet?

Is there an entirely different way I could go about receiving the response?  I still need to broadcast, because this will be run on networks that don't necessarily even have DNS, so I can't rely on things like Zeroconf (not to mention the fact that there's no good Zeroconf support available for Java) to discover the other machines on the network.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't you know the port on which the whole process is happening ? Regards

Comment: if there is firewall, you can't do anything. you can consider the firewall like a cut off wire. also it's very bad idea to modify the firewall settings yourself (and will need to be run as administrator)

Comment: Well, for the receiving port number, I can either statically allocate one, or I can let the OS decide and pass that info to the remote machine in the broadcast packet.  So, I guess I could inform the firewall of a specific port, but I'd like to know how all these other programs configure this without involving the user.

Comment: I think the simplest answer would be to find a way to let Windows know that the in-coming packets are solicited.  If I were to make an out-going TCP connection, then in-coming packets for the same connection would work just fine.  Unfortunately, the out-going packet HAS to be UDP, because it HAS to be broadcast (versus possibly hundreds of TCP attempts).  Is there slightly connection-oriented datagram protocol I could use?

Answer (score 3):

There are three things to consider with respect to the firewall:

1. The simplest way to "open" a port in the firewall is to have the program behind the firewall send a datagram to its peer.  This (usually) creates a temporary rule allowing return datagrams from the peer to the local program.  However, Windows Vista and Windows 7 will only do this if the local program has been authorized to communicate on the network.  When you first run the program, a dialog box will appear asking whether to allow it to talk to the network.  If you click anything other than "Allow Access", then the program will be permanently blocked.
2. The best way is for a user with admin privileges to manually open whatever port number(s) the program is listening and/or sending upon.
3. Even if you open a port, some firewall may still block your datagrams.  This can result from something as obscure as the first few bytes of your payload coincidentally matching some pattern the firewall doesn't like.  For example, Symantic Antivirus may block any UDP
   datagram whose first few bytes are `0x20 0x01 0x00 0x00` because it assumes this is a Teredo tunnel.  Likewise, if your datagrams are just a few bytes larger the the path MTU, some firewalls will see a small IP fragment and drop it to prevent an ancient DoS attack vector.

My recommendation is to choose between 1 or 2 based on the needs of your application, and try to avoid 3 by setting the first few bytes of each datagram to something constant and keeping your datagrams below 1400 bytes each.